# Bitcoin Wiki mirror?

Tags: bitcoin-wiki

Are there mirrors of the Bitcoin Wiki?

<sup>(https://en.bitcoin.it/ is down.)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is now :)

http://welshcomputing.com/bitcoin/wiki/en/Main_Page

About/limitations: http://welshcomputing.com/bitcoin/

Comment: It appears this has not been updated since May 2015...

Comment: About time for an update eh? Got the text, will work on images in a bit.