# Is bitcoin mining completely automated?

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin-core, mining-pools

What I mean by "completely automated" is, if all the below are taken care of by the client, no human effort is involved.

- Collecting the transactions
- Creating a new block

If possible can someone explain or redirect me to a *resource explaining the whole mining process in detail with technical specifics.*

Can a miner choose which transactions should go in which respective block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, these tasks are normally taken care of by Bitcoin Core or equivalent mining software.

I suppose in principle some miner could patch their software so that it asked a human operator to approve each transaction before adding to a block, or to participate in some other way.  But I can't imagine why anybody would want to, or what a human would look for in a transaction that wouldn't be easier to script.

For more general information about mining, see [What exactly is Mining?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/148/what-exactly-is-mining/760#760) The main source of technical information about Bitcoin is the wiki at https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Mining (or a [mirror](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/37569/bitcoin-wiki-mirror)).